# Ant: Two questions about dirsets

Tags: java, apache, ant

I have two questions about the [dirset type](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/dirset.html) in Apache Ant.

- Is a dirset really a set, with no order guaranteed, or does it preserves the input order?
  I want to use ant:contrib to iterate over a set of directories and order matters, so if Ant's dirset does not preserve insertion-order, what alternatives do I have?
- How can I test if a certain dir is included within a dirset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Edit]**

If you look at the dirset [source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/DirectoryScanner.java?view=markup) It looks like it uses java `File.list()`, whose [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29) states that there is no gauranteed order. <strike>So no you can't count on that absolutely.</strike> However, before returning it calls `Arrays.sort(files);` See Line 1572.

---

<strike>As per preserving order I couldn't say, I would hazard that there is no guarantee but that it usually just happens to preserve the file systems order.</strike>

As to testing, I presume you want, do action if this file exists or something similar, using ant contrib,

```
<for param="directory">
<dirset dir="dirIneedtoexist">
</dirset>
<sequential>
     <!-- Stuff to do if it exists. -->          
</sequential>
</for>
```

If there is nothing in the dirset if won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much in the Ant documentation about [dirset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/dirset.html).

If you use `patternset`, there's no guarantee of order.

If you use `include`, listing individual directories rather than patterns, `dirset` should preserve the order.  I'd test this though, to be sure.

Edited to add: In the event that I'm wrong, you can write your own [Ant custom task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html) to preserve the order of the include directories.

Comment: I spoke too soon.  As Andrew points out, inserted files are [sorted](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/ant/ant-1.6.4/org/apache/tools/ant/DirectoryScanner.java.html#line.1299) so insertion order is not preserved.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: The array sort is in a method that deals with include patterns.  I'd have to spend way more time studying the dirset source code to be sure.  It'd be quicker to test what I've said.

Comment: there is no code-path for included files that does not go through the directory scanner and without such tests, your answer seems content free.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html)

> dirset Adds a directory set to the implicit build path. Note that the directories will be added to the build path in no particular order, so if order is significant, one should use a file list instead!

Here's link on how to use [FileList](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filelist.html)

Answer (score 0):

No it does not preserve order.

A dirset's contents are based on what its [parent class](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/ant/ant-1.6.4/org/apache/tools/ant/types/AbstractFileSet.java.html#line.340) exposes via a [`DirectoryScanner`](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/ant/ant-1.6.4/org/apache/tools/ant/DirectoryScanner.java.html#line.1028).  That scanner walks the file system and does not do so in any particular order.

It also uses [`File.list`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29) which is a source of order non-determinism:

> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular, guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.

Comment: They [sort](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/ant/ant-1.6.4/org/apache/tools/ant/DirectoryScanner.java.html#line.1299) it before returning though.

Comment: @Andrew, they sort the result of the included files there, not the results of the directory scan.